# How to achieve a floating logo layout between two background views?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve a layout similar to the second layout of this image [image: this picture] I would like to have a background image take about 40% of the screen and then a view below it with my content but I would like my logo to float in between the two. Similar to how the "G" sits between the image and the content. I tried having two views and nesting the logo inside the first view and tried to position absolute but I am having trouble centering it horizontally, making it 10% of the width and having a perfect circle, because it seems you cant use flex attributes on an absolute positioned element.

Here is my attempt

https://snack.expo.io/HkV0wEptE

Answer (score 0):

To centered the logo, you can just put it in a View that have screen width and sets the alignItems to 'center'. Below are a simple sample of how to do this layout:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={myStyle.container}>
        <View style={myStyle.topBanner} />
        <View style={myStyle.contentArea}>
          <Text style={myStyle.contentTitle}>HERE LIES CONTENT</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={myStyle.midLogoRow}>
          <Image style={myStyle.midLogo} source={require('../../images/profile_achive.png')} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

and the stylesheet is as below:

```
const sWidth  = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const sHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const myStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: sWidth,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  topBanner: {
    width: sWidth,
    height: sHeight * 0.4,
    backgroundColor: '#c5c5c5',
  },
  midLogoRow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: sHeight * 0.3,
    left: 0,
    width: sWidth,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  midLogo: {
    width: sHeight * 0.18,
    height: sHeight * 0.18,
  },
  contentArea: {
    marginTop: sHeight * 0.09,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  contentTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#333',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

as you can see; the row where the your logo's in (in my case it's profile_achieve.png) is placed at the lowest part so that it will be render on top of everything else. The top margin for the contentArea is set at 0.09 of screen height, which is logo height divide by 2.